# Mysql select query not retrieving decimal value

Tags: mysql

I have sizes table with decimal and non-decimal value so I want to fetch data as per requirement and I have written mysql query for this, but getting empty result even data is present.

Note:I don't want to use LIKE clause

Table:

```
id      size
1       17X23
2       28.3X39.8 
3       25X39.8
4       28X36
```

Mysql query:

```
Select * from sizes where size='28.3X39.8'; // X is uppercase 'X' alphabet I have used to mention width X height
```

Output: empty result

Comment: We need your tables descriptions to help you

Comment: @Claus Bönnhoff I am storing widthXheight values which contain decimal and non-decimal value and to represent multiplication symbol I am using X

Comment: As presented here, your code works as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dadecc/1

Comment: You have a serious data type problem

Comment: I guess he does not even now which datatype his columns are. Elsewhere he would show us his table description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be  you have some hidden space

```
select Select * from sizes where trim(size)='28.3X39.8';
```

or

```
select Select * from sizes where trim(replace(size,' ',''))='28.3X39.8';
```

or

```
select Select * from sizes where upper(trim(replace(size,' ','')))=uppper(trim('28.3X39.8'));
```

Comment: I tried both queries , still didn't get any output

Comment: answer  updated with another suggestion too..  anyway which data type is the column  size??

Comment: varchar data type used, I tried all suggested queries but I am surprised why none of then working

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: exit and reenter in your ide  or db console first  ..  restart your db service  . or restart you server .. .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select * from sizes where trim(upper(size))='28.3X39.8';
```